# How to root android device with lollipop without internet connection

Tags: rooting, 5.1-lollipop

I want to root my smartphone to use reverse tethering but when I install apps KingRoot, KingoRoot they require internet connection
How to root without internet connection?

Comment: Did you try the desktop software version? iRoot desktop doesn't require internet connection. BTW, which device is that?

Comment: thx no I try :) ! sony xperia z1

Comment: Oh oh! Rooting a Sony device is not easy. You need to unlock the bootloader first!

Comment: but I used only KingoRoot Windows version and done rooted

Comment: Oh lucky you! Your bootloader was probably already unlocked. Congrats

Comment: Reverse tethering (for TCP and UDP) is possible without root access using https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet (disclaimer: I'm the author).